# I want to unbind the click event on button click which is done using knockout.js for a list item

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I want to unbind the click event on input:button click which is done using knockout.js for a list items except last list item in the list."Using Jquery" **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mystudies/xFH4J/)**

```
<ul class="list-tabs" data-bind="foreach: Steps()">
                <li data-bind="attr:{'id':Id()},
                               css:$root.cssForMenu(StatusText(), Id()),
                               click: $root.chosenStep" id="1" class="Complete">
                    <span data-bind="text: DisplayText">Step1</span>
                </li>

                <li data-bind="attr:{'id':Id()},
                               css:$root.cssForMenu(StatusText(), Id()),
                               click: $root.chosenStep" id="2" class="Complete">
                    <span data-bind="text: DisplayText">Step2</span>
                </li>


                <li data-bind="attr:{'id':Id()},
                               css:$root.cssForMenu(StatusText(), Id()),
                               click: $root.chosenStep" id="4" class="Complete">
                    <span data-bind="text: DisplayText">Step3</span>
                </li>

                <li data-bind="attr:{'id':Id()},
                               css:$root.cssForMenu(StatusText(), Id()),
                               click: $root.chosenStep" id="5" class="Complete">
                    <span data-bind="text: DisplayText">Step4</span>
                </li>

</ul>
<input type="button" id="disable">
```

The only thing i have to do is after clicking the button#disable i need to disabled all the step item click return false for permanent. Can anybody help me pls. its on hire priority

Comment: It is not clear that you want to remove the event from all list items, or all but the last one? Because you wrote the former before the code and the latter after the code.

Comment: Sorry, i cant quite understand what you are attempting to do, could you also show us your viewmodel? thanks.

Comment: we can achive it by jquery? or not

Comment: on click of left step items i'am calling the respective templates when its come on last step template there is submit button on click of that all left step items has to be non-clickable except last list step i mean "Step4" should be still active

Comment: Try and avoid using jQuery and knockout at the same time. Also that fiddle is not using knockout at all as it's not referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var steps = $('list-tabs li');
steps.each(function(index, element) {
   if (index != steps.length - 1) {
     element.unbind('click');
   }
};
```

Edit:

Thanks for the JS fiddle. First of all you need to bind this code to the button click event.
And I also find the problem. So here is what is working:

```
$('#disable').click(disable);
```

You need this to handle the button click.

```
function disable(){
  var steps = $('.list-tabs li');
  $(steps).each(function(index, element) {
    if (index !== steps.length - 1) {
      $(element).unbind('click');
    }
  });
}
```

And this to remove the click events on the list items.

It worked for me on your JsFiddle.

Comment: Updated the answer based on your JsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle showing how to do it using Knockout.

You will notice i only manipulate the model and allow KO to do the rest.

You may also notice that i have an enable binding on the li, this is actually doing nothing as it does not work on a li, this is why i am doing a check in Step `if (!active()) return;` to prevent the click from happening. If you was to change the li to a button the enable will work and you could remove that check.

## [(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Kohan/xFH4J/7/)

## JS

```
function Step(number) {
    this.active = ko.observable(true);
    this.name = ko.observable("Step " + number);

    this.clickme = function() {
        if (!this.active()) return;

        alert(this.name());
    };
}

var model = function () {
    var items = ko.observableArray(
         [new Step(1), new Step(2), new Step(3), new Step(4)]);

    var disableAllBut4 = function () {
        items().forEach(function (item) {
            item.active(false);
        });

        items()[3].active(true);
    }

    var enableAll = function () {
        items().forEach(function (item) {
            item.active(true);
        });
    }

    return {
        items: items,
        disable: disableAllBut4,
        enableAll: enableAll
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

## HTML

```
<h4>want to stop click event except step4</h4>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: name, click: clickme, enable: active, css:{disabled: !active()}"></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="disable" data-bind="click: disable" value="Disable">
<input type="button" id="disable" data-bind="click: enableAll" value="Enable all">
```

## CSS

```
.disabled {
    color: red;
}
```